# Model relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-models, relationship

I have a model for conversations between two users.

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    recipient1_pk = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    recipient2_pk = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And I have a child model for messages.  I'd to include a Boolean field that would allow each user to toggle the visibility of the conversation.  BUT I don't want this to affect the conversation for the other user so I can't just add it to the conversation model.  Is there an efficient way for me to add a boolean field for each user to do this whilst still sharing the same conversation model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at adding extra fields to your `ManyToManyField` [via the `through` parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships):

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='ConversationPreferences')
    recipient1_pk = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    recipient2_pk = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ConversationPreferences(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation)
    visibility = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: You would need a foreign key to `Conversation` model too in the though table

Comment: I just finished updating the models and it's turned out to be just what I needed.  Thank you.